# Using a set, find if num exists as a sum of 2 numbers in an array

Tags: ruby, set

I need to find if two numbers in an array equal a specific digit or not.

```
def sum?(array, num)
end

sum?([1, 2, 3], 5) #=> true
sum?([1, 2, 3], 6) #=> false
```

Is there a solution using a set whose order is less than N^2? Also, is there a way to get under N^2 without using a set?

Comment: The number of combinations is less than *O(N^2)* but it's still pretty punishing in terms of how many tests you need to do. Is it only positive integers? You can discard numbers higher than your target *m* obviously.

Comment: Is this "two numbers" as in "sum of two numbers"?

Comment: And can those two numbers actually be at the same location in the array (implying the two numbers are equal), or do they have to be at different locations?

Comment: Yes, 'two numbers' did mean 'sum of two numbers' in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a set, lookup of a specific number is approximately constant. For each number in the array, there is only one other number that can make the sum work. Scanning the array is linear.

```
require 'set'

def sum?(array, num)
  set = array.to_set
  array.any? { |x| set.include?(num - x) }
end
```

The set conversion is approximately linear (N inserts), the `any?` is linear since the worst case iterates over each element once, and each element has an approximately constant lookup in the set. So overall linear.

This method fails if `num` is even and the array contains a single copy of `num/2`. That is another linear check, which I'll leave as an exercise.

Comment: The question is a bit hazy but does seem to imply that a sum is required.

Comment: You're missing a `do` and should probably mention `require 'set'`.

Comment: @tadman the sum is implicit. If the array includes both `x` and `num-x` then it contains two numbers that sum to `num`

Comment: Ah, true, good point. That won't scale to three numbers but it should work for two. This should perform fairly well so long as the construction cost on the set is fairly linear.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph of the answer: I think your code will work fine if the array is `[num/2]`.  Then `num - x` equals `x`, and `include?` returns true, so `any?` returns true.

Comment: @DavidGrayson The question says "sum of two numbers" so I think it would need to be `[num/2,num/2]` in order to be true.

Comment: @Max Thanks. This worked great along with a check to make sure num - x doesn't equal x

Answer (score 0):

The naive strategy here is pretty simple:

```
def sum?(array, n)
  array.reject do |v|
    v >= n
  end.combination(2).any? do |a, b|
    a + b == n
  end
end
```

Using a `Set` seems pretty heavy-handed as you'd have to compute the entire set of all possible sums. For repeated tests it would be more efficient, you only need to compute the set once, but for single tests it's less efficient. This really depends on your use case.

For example:

```
def sum?(array, n)
  Set.new(
    array.reject do |v|
      v >= n
    end.combination(2).map do |a, b|
      a + b
    end
  ).include?(n)
end
```

You could try benchmarking that to see what the performance is like with longer lists of numbers.

Comment: Note, (as implied in your  [comment up above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401957/using-a-set-in-ruby-find-if-num-exists-as-a-sum-of-2-numbers-in-an-array#comment81757855_47401957) that you should only run the `reject { v >= n }` if you're guaranteed to have only positive integers...otherwise a number larger than target plus a negative number could bring it back down to equality.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a set based solution. If you want to avoid imports, you could use rubys "Enumerable#uniq" function instead (also implemented in Array), which creates a new array without dublicate entries. The next step would be to determine the minimum int value of your array and subtract that from your wished sum value. The value calculated like this is the maximum allowed value you have. You can then reject the others. All the operations so far seem to be O(N) according to the C-Code in the ruby docs. In the end you can use the Enumerable#any? function, as in your pereferd solution.

Here goes some untested code:

```
    def sum?(array,num)
       rest = array.uniq
       max_allowed = num - rest.min
       rest.reject! {|value| value > max_allowed}
       rest.any? {|value| rest.include?(num - value)}
    end
```

For the calculation:
array.uniq is pretty much the same as a tranformation into a set, so lets skip this.
calculating max allowed is O(1) + O(N)
rejection is O(N)
any? should result in avg of O(N * log(N))

which makes the result: O(1) + 2 * O(N) + O(N * log(N))
according to the big O notation this is O(N * log(N)) as it is the biggest part which is less then O(N^2)